# htaccess mod_rewrite query string parameter path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the current url
`https://www.japaneseguesthouses.com/ryokan-single/?ryokan=Fukiko`

to 
`https://www.japaneseguesthouses.com/ryokan-single/Fukiko`

I tried this one

Yes

```
RewriteRule ^(ryokan-single)/?$ /?ryokan=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]\ /\?ryokan=([^\s&]+)? [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /ryokan-single/%1? [R=301,L]
```

please need solution

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I did one code example

Comment: Try this way.

`RewriteRule ^ryokan-single/([^/]*)/$ /ryokan-single/?ryokan=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: didn' worked that too :-(

Comment: Is `/ryokan-single/` a real directory? Does it have a .htaccess?